# DC-DC Converter Voltage and Current Regulation

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I am trying to get a better understanding of how the voltage and current regulation in a standard flyback converter works. I have simulated a scenario where a 5V DC-DC converter is powered up with no load. At T=2ms, I subject the converter to a sudden resistive-capacitive load. As expected, the capacitive load results in a high inrush. What exactly is happening in the converter during time periods A and B where the voltage ramps up? How does that operation work?

See plot for reference. The top plot is the output voltage of the converter and the bottom plot is the output current.[image]

Comment: Please don't use node references; name the nodes on the schematic and plot with respect to those nodes.

Comment: Added node labels

Comment: Try lowering C2 from 100 uF to 33 uF and see if the sudden downward transition starts sooner after point (a). Also, what is the on resistance of the changeover switch?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you need a minimum load at the output to keep the output voltage in regulation (datasheet on page 9 says so for this module).

This module has an built-in soft-start circuit. It will have another behaviour at startup (A) and during operation (B).

Voltage and current regulation in a standard flyback converter: depends on the controller. There are controllers with isolated feedback, there are also controllers which sense the V_D of the FET.

If you want to know how a flyback operates, then you can get many info on the web.
Starting points:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_converter
- https://www.coilcraft.com/en-us/edu/series/a-guide-to-flyback-transformers/